# How to control web browser using some programming language?

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control

I am looking for a way to control a web browser such as firefox or chrome. I need something like "selenium webdriver" but that will allow me to open many instances URL load, get http headers, response code, get response content, load time, etc.

Is there any library, framework, api that I could use to do it? I couldn't find one exactly that does all, selenium opens browser and go to url but I can't get http headers

Answer (score 0):

Selenium and Jellyfish are strong options in general. Jellyfish is an option that uses Node.js - although I have no experience with it, I've heard good things from my colleagues.

If you just want to get headers and such, you could use the cURL library or wget. I've used cURL with NuSOAP to query XML web services in PHP, for example. The downside is that these are not functional browsers, and merely perform the HTTP requests and consume the response.

---

- http://seleniumhq.org/
- https://github.com/admc/jellyfish
- http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: But I really need to execute it in a broswer, I need a real environment for testing purposes such as performance. So curl and selenium doesn't meet my requeriments. Am I able to do it with Jellyfish?

Comment: There appears to be the capability to check status codes using this codebase: https://github.com/wdavidw/node-http-status